# Reroute HttpHandler to MVC action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My page is generating HTML with the following URL pattern:

```
<img src="../cachedimagehandler.axd?data=6ee6d0ee-8490-4583-848c-6c832b011e17" >
```

I cannot change the URL generated.

`cachedimagehandler.axd` is supposed to be an HttpHandler in an external library that fetches that image from the Http cache. For some reason, it's not working in this MVC project.

Is there a way for me to redirect these URLs and the data key to an MVC controller action in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if creating a route will work, but try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "CacheImage",                                              // Route name
                "cachedimagehandler.axd",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "CachedImage"}  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Also, make sure you comment out this line:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```